# How to rectify class cast exception on tools.MapsActivity to location.LocationListener in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Here its my logcat

> 12-01 14:53:24.164 17910-17910/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.swetha.pc.barcoderead, PID: 17910
>                                                                              java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.swetha.pc.barcoderead.tools.MapsActivity cannot be cast to
>   android.location.LocationListener
>                                                                                  at
>   com.swetha.pc.barcoderead.tools.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:265)
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
>                                                                                  at zu.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
>                                                                                  at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 12-01
>   14:53:25.020 17910-20204/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead I/b: Received API
>   Token:
>   AH0uPGEAVz4Fv0lIM1ZNa72XhP7ITCAK41eqC_INs_c63sE2LxzjlfURVrWkQ33r8PUe1ED9uW8HZEVSk6NjJG53kHmlU9iLrTrWXo57bcxPrqgeUEzTkfgKd9m6wuh93aolf3k47OakjOpk2uGiJtC8UNMq-VUQ8V4-HxgAA-ZQIrm_GsYUZXi42JEYrAG2k9IDosUy9xfJ
>   / Expires in: 432000000ms 12-01 14:53:25.020
>   17910-20204/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead I/c: Scheduling next attempt in
>   431700 seconds. 12-01 14:53:25.022
>   17910-20204/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation 12-01 14:53:25.023
>   17910-20204/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead I/d: Saved auth token 12-01
>   14:53:25.027 17910-20265/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead W/f: Suppressed
>   StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 12-01
>   14:53:26.070 17910-20198/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead W/DynamiteModule:
>   Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found. 12-01
>   14:53:26.089 17910-20198/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead I/DynamiteModule:
>   Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0
>   and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2 12-01
>   14:53:26.089 17910-20198/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead I/DynamiteModule:
>   Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates,
>   version >= 2 12-01 14:53:26.093 17910-20198/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead
>   E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load DynamiteLoader:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] 12-01 14:53:26.093 17910-20198/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead
>   W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load remote module: Failed to get module
>   context 12-01 14:53:26.093 17910-20198/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead
>   W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module via fast routetn: Remote load
>   failed. No local fallback found. 12-01 14:53:26.096
>   17910-20198/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead W/DynamiteModule: Local module
>   descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not
>   found. 12-01 14:53:26.101 17910-20198/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead
>   I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2 12-01 14:53:26.101
>   17910-20198/com.swetha.pc.barcoderead I/DynamiteModule: Selected
>   remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version
>
> > = 2

Comment: You are casting a com.swetha.pc.barcoderead.tools.MapsActivity type to android.location.LocationListener in Line number com.swetha.pc.barcoderead.tools.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:265).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your DataActivity implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener and not android.location.LocationListener.
You may have imported android.location.LocationListener by mistake.
Dont cast it.

Happy coding